# How do I set specific id on an html form element within a content placeholder in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page in asp.net. I have an ASPX with a master page that has its HTML elements in `contentplaceholder1`.

Now, when I place an element with `<asp:Label ID="myID" runat="server" />`, the id of that html element is `contentplaceholder1_myID`, but I want it to be `myID` for my convenience.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What's possible is the other way around: Knowing what its ID will be in the client code. After that, you can renderize that ID and use it. If you are interested, I can write an answer with that.

Comment: I'm doing that right now, but I wanted to know if it is possible?

Comment: one of the drawbacks of using webforms is that the code gets bloated and ugly like that. Consider using something more clean, like asp.net mvc or angular

Comment: thank you @Stormhashe, but I'm limited by the technology of my office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 4 or above, you can use the new `ClientIDMode`. From the documentation, it has four modes (I think you want to use the `static` mode):

> **AutoID**
>
> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each
>   parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In
>   data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are
>   rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's
>   ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).
>   This algorithm was used in versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET 4.
>
> **Static**
>
> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.
>
> **Predictable**
>
> This algorithm is used for controls that are in data-bound controls.
>   The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ClientID value of
>   the parent naming container with the ID value of the control. If the
>   control is a data-bound control that generates multiple rows, the
>   value of the data field specified in the ClientIDRowSuffix property is
>   added at the end. For the GridView control, multiple data fields can
>   be specified. If the ClientIDRowSuffix property is blank, a sequential
>   number is added at the end instead of a data-field value. This number
>   begins at zero and is incremented by 1 for each row. Each segment is
>   separated by an underscore character (_).
>
> **Inherit**
>
> The control inherits the ClientIDMode setting of its NamingContainer
>   control.

You can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Control_ClientIDMode). Hope it helps.